# Update .NET Core 3.1.5 on my server Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I installing the Hosting Bundle 3.1.4 on my server Windows Server 2012 R2, which includes the .NET Core Runtime and IIS support. Now, it's available ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.5 and I want update my server.

Should I install only the runtime "ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.5" or again "the Hosting Bundle 3.1.5"?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.5 has IIS runtime support (ASP.NET Core Module v2) version 13.1.20142.5

ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.4 has IIS runtime support (ASP.NET Core Module v2) version 13.1.20114.4

If you want all work well together, and use lastest stable stack, uninsall *Hosting Bundle 3.1.4* , install *Hosting Bundle 3.1.5*

Reference: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Let's see (tip: Open image in new tab for bigger screenshot)

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: ok, but after i install Hosting Bundle 3.1.5 it is necessary uninstall Hosting Bundle 3.1.4?
if both are installed is the most recent version 3.1.5 used by running applications?